# Array Structure: Very Long Array List (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, parsing

I have a very long list of URLs, from which I am cycling through and parsing JSON text. The list of URLs is too long for how I have it structured below (`urlArray = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5"`) as the URLs eventually separate onto two lines and I receive errors that can only be rectified by shortening the URL list array back to one line (of long code). (Note: if you believe I can fix this original structure/syntax, please let me know as it works with <7 URLs)

I changed my URL array to the following format (only replacing `urlArray = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5"` noted above and seen below):

```
urlArray(1) = "URL1"
urlArray(2) = "URL2"
urlArray(3) = "URL3"
urlArray(4) = "URL4"
urlArray(5) = "URL5"
```

When I do change to this new format, I receive a run-time error '5':

> Invalid procedure call or argument

highlighting `.Open "GET", MyUrls(k)`

So, my question is, can I change my format to this new structure? Or, should I go in another direction given my circumstances (very long list of URLs that doesn't seem to work in first format)?

Full code pre-change:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getJSON()

Dim sheetCount As Integer, urlArray As Variant
sheetCount = 1

urlArray = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5", "etc.")

Dim MyRequest As Object: Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim MyUrls: MyUrls = urlArray
Dim k As Long
Dim Json As Object

For k = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)

    With MyRequest
        .Open "GET", MyUrls(k)
        .Send
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)

        Dim i As Long, p As Object

        For i = 1 To Json("prices").Count
            Set p = Json("prices")(i)
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 1) = p("name")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 2) = p("cost")("fareType")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 9) = p("cost")("base")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 10) = p("cost")("perMinute")
        Next i

    End With

    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: are your URLs legal ? I am able to pass that line using a valud URL (Google)

Comment: @shaiRado I'm not sure what you mean by "legal" -- but the pre-change code above works perfectly before the URL list gets *TOO* long (i.e., extends to multiple rows).

Comment: what is your "URL1" for instance ? if you can share that information

Answer (score 2):

An underscore `_` allows you to continue the code onto the next line.

```
Sub getJSON()

Dim sheetCount As Integer, urlArray As Variant
sheetCount = 1

urlArray = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5", "URL6", "URL7", _
            "URL8", "URL9", "URL10", "URL11", "URL12", "URL13", "URL14", _
            "URL15", "URL16", "URL17", "URL18", "URL19", "URL20")

Dim MyRequest As Object: Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim MyUrls: MyUrls = urlArray
Dim k As Long
Dim Json As Object

For k = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)

    With MyRequest
        .Open "GET", MyUrls(k)
        .Send
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)

        Dim i As Long, p As Object

        For i = 1 To Json("prices").Count
            Set p = Json("prices")(i)
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 1) = p("name")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 2) = p("cost")("fareType")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 9) = p("cost")("base")
            Sheets("Sheet" & sheetCount).Cells(i, 10) = p("cost")("perMinute")
        Next i

    End With

    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
Next k

End Sub
```

You might want to iterate over you array using a `For Each` loop.

```
Dim k As Variant

For k = LBound(MyUrls) To UBound(MyUrls)

    With MyRequest
        .Open "GET", k
```

I would store the Urls on the spreadsheet:

[image]

You can load them into your array like this:

[image]

```
Dim MyUrls
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MyUrls = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the underscore goes AFTER the comma!